# SwiftUI Text doesn't expand the row of the List

Tags: swift, swiftui, swiftui-list

I am currently trying to make the text expand my SwiftUI List`s rows.

Any ideas what is wrong it ?

Here is the List:
[image]

[image]

And the code for the cell

Comment: If you want them to expand vertically, I'd suggest removing .lineLimit(0) from the lessonDescription text.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a fix:

[image: demo]   // << remove .lineLimit !!

Tested with Xcode 13.3 / iOS 15.4